# How can I tell which marker is being dragged an a Google Maps API drag event?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The "drag", "dragstart" and "dragend" events in the Google Maps V3 API each pass a mouseEvent to the registered callback function.

However - this event does not contain any information as to *which marker* is being dragged. How can I determine that?

This is even more complicated if you are just looking at the "dragend" event - which would only have the *new* coordinates, making it impossible to even infer from the coordinates.

I'd assume there's got to be an easy way to just determine which marker is being dragged...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would attach add the drag event to the marker using a listener when it is created.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
                //do something with the event.
            });
```

here is an example fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/2YQg6/10/
(Dont mind the other stuff I just edited a fiddle I have used before to handle draggable markers.)

The relavant code is in the marker creation loop:

```
//geo code and build markers for each list item.
for (var i = 0; i < $listItems.length; i++) {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': $($listItems[i]).text()
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                originalPos: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent("marker originally at this position: " + this.originalPos + " was dragged to: " + this.position);
                infoWindow.open(map, this);
            });


            markers.push(marker);
        }        

});
}
```

Comment: Long story short, the "this" keyword in your listener function will point to your marker

Comment: cannot stress enough the usefulness of Dannys comment, as i cannot find that info anywhere in Googles documentation.

Comment: `this` would not be in Google's documentation since it is part of the JavaScript language. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Comment: @Bryan Weaver ... how can I find marker instance using ES6's anonymous function syntax i.e. using ()=>{ } for the dragend event handler ?